# How can I automatically execute gulp task when I publish an application using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, gulp

I am using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with an ASP.NET MVC project. I have [Task Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TaskRunnerExplorer) installed in my Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

Every time I publish a new version to the server, I have to always remember to first run a task that generates my publish resources "production ready".

Is there a way to setup the project where it always executes a `gulp` command line before it publish?

Here is the command that I am looking to execute

```
cmd.exe /c gulp -b --gulpfile "gulpfile.js" production
```

http://gulpjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom build configuration for publishing alongside with DEBUG and RELEASE and run this command on post-build stage

Comment: Right-click on project, select "properties" and go to the "Build Events" tab. You should use "Post-build event command line". Probably, it'll be necessary to fix paths with environment variables ("Edit Post-build..." button will help you).

Comment: I added this code. but it is going me an error `IF ($(ConfigurationName) == "Production")
{
      gulp --type=production
} 
ELSE 
{
      gulp
}`

Comment: Use post-build in following way:
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (<do something>)
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (<do something>)
if $(ConfigurationName) == Production (<do something>)

Also you can use goto statements to not repeat youself

Comment: Still erroring. this command is returning an error `IF ($(ConfigurationName) == Production)
(
      
)
ELSE 
(
      
)`

Comment: Do not use ELSE

Comment: same thing even without it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132444/discussion-between-yury-glushkov-and-jaylen).

Comment: This is not the right answer because you asked how to run gulp after publishing not after building.